# Meaning of a notation regarding mean square derivative

Tags: derivative, functional-data-analysis

I'm reading a paper (On Differentiable Functionals, Van der Vaart, 1991, Annals of Statistics), and I've got a question regarding a notation in the following part:

[image]

**My Question:** Does $dP^{1/2}$ mean $d(P)^{1/2}$ or $(dP)^{1/2}$? 
 It would be great if you could explain why.

Thanks!